# Can a warlock who has 5th level spell slots make spell scrolls of level 1 following XGE scroll making rules?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, warlock, crafting, downtime

So, following XGE spell casters can make scrolls in their downtime. Now if a warlock has 5th level slots does he have to make spell scrolls of 5th level?
Like for example a 5th level *hex* scroll.

The issue comes as spells of different level take different costs and time in XGE.
So, If I want to make 1st level *hex* spell scroll can I make one?

Answer (score 8):

### You can create scrolls of the spell's normal level

By default, the minimum level of a spell is used when creating a magic item that can cast spells (p. 141 *DMG*):

> Some magic items allow the user to cast a spell from the item. **The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level**, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise.

The rules for spell scrolls in the DMG do not change or contradict this.

*Xanathar's Guide* only changes the rules for *crafting* items, not the rules for the items themselves, so it does not change it either. *Xanathar's* has new general rules for creating items and an exception to those for "Scribing a Scroll" on p. 133:

> Scribing a spell scroll takes an amount of time and money related to the level of the spell the character wants to scribe, as shown in the Spell Scroll Costs table. In addition, the character must have **proficiency in the Arcana skill** and must **provide any material components** required for the casting of the spell. Moreover, the character **must have the spell prepared, or it must be among the character's known spells**, in order to scribe a scroll of that spell.

These new requirements for creating a scroll differ from the normal *DMG* rules (p. 129) that would require you to have a **matching level spell slot**. They now merely demand:

- proficiency in the Arcana skill
- material components
- the spell [. . .] must be among the character's known spells

*Hex* is on the warlock spell list so you can pick it as a known spell. Assuming you have the material components, the warlock is proficient in Arcana, and the warlock picked it as one of his known spells (*PHB*, p. 106) all three of those requirements are fulfilled.

So yes, you can create a first level *hex* scroll that uses the normal, minimum level of the spell, and no, you cannot create a 5th level *hex* scroll. As a first level spell scroll, this would cost you 1 day of work and 25 gp by the table on p. 133, *XGE*.

Comment: I’m sure that’s not how “known spells” classes work! Bards, Sorcerers, Warlocks and so on only know a limited number of spells from their lists. The ones granted as they level up, and any additional ones granted by class features (like Additional Spells from a subclass or some Eldritch Invocations). They don’t know all the spells on their class spell list, or they’d be able to cast any spell on the list at any time, making swapping out spells as they level up pointless.

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie, yes -- I wanted to express that they can have the spell as a "known" spell, but I can see how the wording was misleading. I fixed that (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

### Magic items can have spells of higher than minimum level

Magic items times may specify the level version of a spell that can be cast while using them. Prominent examples of this are the [staff of power](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4764-staff-of-power) and staff of the magi.  Spell scrolls are magic items so can specify the level version of the spell they allow the user to cast.

#### Crafting Costs and Scroll Level

Scribing a *scroll of fireball 5th-level version* would not be a 3rd level scroll.  [It would be 5th level scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpellataHigherLevel):

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level

It will have considerably greater cost to create at 5,000gp instead of the 500gp a third level scroll requires to manufacture using Xanathar's Guide to Everything (XGtE) downtime rules.

> Scribing a spell scroll takes an amount of time and money related to the level of the spell

Additionally, there is an increase in the chances of complications during the activity as a 5th level scroll takes 4 weeks instead of the 1 week of a 3rd level scroll.

> Crafting a spell scroll is a solitary task, unlikely to attract much attention. The complications that arise are more likely to involve the preparation needed for the activity. Every workweek spent scribing brings a 10 percent chance of a complication, examples of which are on the Scribe a Scroll Complications table.

### Summary

- Creating a *scroll of hex* would take a day, cost 25gp, and have no chance of complication.
- Creating a *scroll of hex 5th-level* would take 4 weeks, cost 5000gp, and have four chances of complications arising.